# Remove links that ID matches ID's in array jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I need to remove links that `id` matches the `id` in array. Heres the code:

```
   for(let i = 0; i < allyList.length; i++) {
    if ( $.inArray(allyList[i], allyArray) > -1 ) {
        // In this if statement I'm checking if id's from allyList matches id's allyArray
    }
   }
```

This code ^ above works fine. It checks if ID's matches. But now I have this link:

```
<a href="/join-alliance/{{this.title}}" id="{{this._id}}" class="btn btn-success join">Join</a>
```

These links `id` is all the same as `allyList` id's. I need to somehow get these links in array and then check in that if statement above if the links `id's` matches the ones in `allyList`.  And if the `id` matches I need to remove that link.

Comment: this "link" looks like a template, and not real link... this is correct? if so ... so you need to scan the links again after to DOM has changed

Comment: This link is in loop. So theres multiple of them and each have unique id.

Comment: Do you want to retain those array values after redirection?

Comment: After redirection I save the ID in database. allyList have those id's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood correctly then link that has the id in allyArray that needs to be removed from dom.

```
 $(".join").each(function() {
       if(allyArray.indexOf($(this).attr("id")) > -1)
          $(this).remove();
  });
```

Comment: glad to hear that:)